# Remove index.php of Codeigniter on IIS?

Tags: windows, codeigniter, iis, url-rewriting

I understand I can remove the 'index.php' part of the url with the following web.config code:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/favicon.ico$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Problem is I have CI installed in a sub-directory (mydomain.com/codeigniter) and I'm having trouble understanding the web.config file.

Do you know how to change this so it works for a sub-directory?

Comment: Have you tried adding subfolder to the rewrite url path? `<action type="Rewrite" url="mysubfolder/index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />`

Comment: Thanks! That works but only if my first rule is not there. I actually need two, one for the top directory and one for the sub-directory.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have WordPress in the root directory and my CodeIgniter application in a sub-directory. I create a similar `web.config` like yours and save it in the sub-directory. My CI app doesn't need the index.php in url any more.

At first, I add my sub-directory in the `<action url="myapp/index.php/{R:1}"...>` and wish it could be restricted to look into the sub-directory only but fails. I remove the sub-directory and leave it to original but move the web.config to the subdirectory and it works.

Therefore, I think maybe you may create two web.config files with different rules and saves them in different directory.

Another note might help: enable the error message to output the detail from IIS. I use the tricks to find out how IIS looks for my files. It is `<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />`, `<asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>`, and the `<system.web>` section as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <system.webServer>

        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
        <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>

        <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="RuleRemoveIndex" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true"/>
            </rule>
        </rules>
        </rewrite>

    </system.webServer>

    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <compilation debug="true"/>
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Make web.config put in the root directory.
>
> User code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
 <system.webServer>

    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>

    <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="RuleRemoveIndex" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true"/>
        </rule>
    </rules>
    </rewrite>

</system.webServer>

<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
</system.web>
```