# CodeIgniter URL - 404 Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I am in the threshold of exploring the CodeIgniter Framework, and I am facing a very basic problem here. I have a controller named pages, and it has a function called view.

**Problem 1:**
Now when I type example.com/myfolder/ I do land to my page. But when I try something like example.com/myfolder/index.php/pages/view or example.com/myfolder/pages/view, it gives me a 404 Error.

**Problem 2:**
I need to remove the index.php from the URL. Please rectify the .htaccess pasted below.

**Controller**

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->view("home");
    }

    public function view($page = 'home') {
        if (!file_exists('application/views/pages/' . $page . '.php')) {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }
        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter
        $data['company_name'] = "Demo Company 2013";
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/' . $page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }

}
```

**Routes**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

**config**

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/myfolder/';
```

**Update**

This might be important. I am running my site on a shared windows hosting, which is using [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services). So I suppose my .htaccess needs to be converted to `web.config`.

**UPDATE WEBCONFIG ADDED**

Now, I have added the web.config from the link provided in one the answers. Thanks a lot; it was really helpful, but still I am getting the same old 404 Error. I tried changing the following my configuration file

```
 $config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';
```

But now I am getting errors about

```
<!doctyle HTML>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You can write your  .htacces like this

```
Options -Indexes

Options +FollowSymLinks

DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
    RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ index.php/$1
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

And check your config.php file and do the changes like this.

```
$config['base_url'] = '';

$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jerin. But it didn't work as expected. I am still getting 404 on both the url's Mentioned.

Comment: Can you remove the route settings and try the url manually?

$route['default_controller'] = 'pages';
$route['404_override'] = '';

like this

Comment: There is nothing you need to focus other than route.php file. The htaccess is perfectly working for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I normally use that works on a number of servers:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /myfolder
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|user_guide|robots\.txt)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

Depending on your server configuration you may need to remove the `?` after `index.php`,

Change:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]`

To:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`

Or else you may get a `404 No input specified` error

Comment: Sorry, I've never run Codeigniter on IIS, this came up in a quick search : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808063/remove-index-php-of-codeigniter-on-iis

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this line is serving the 404:

```
if (!file_exists('application/views/pages/' . $page . '.php')) {
```

Try replacing it with:

```
if (!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/' . $page . '.php')) {
```